# What size type contained by maxrequestLength for http request

Tags: asp.net, asmx, crm, dynamics-crm-4

Could you please tell if I have **maxrequestLength="4096"** then 8192 is a bytes or KB value?

This is set in Web.config file for http request length

Answer (score 1):

The value [represents a size in kilobytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

It's not stated on that linked page, but typically web.config settings representing sizes by way of a number have a limit of `int.MaxValue`, or,  2,147,483,647.